# External json api provides unsanitized character ('DLE' in SublimeText) failing php json_decode

Tags: php, json

I've been using an API for quite some time, without any issues. It gives a list of visitors and the keywords they've been using to land on the site. Suddenly, the script failed. After diving into it, this is caused by a visitor search string containing an invalid character, which failed json_decode:

When looking in notepad (screenshot):

[image]

When looking in SublimeText (screenshot):

[image]

After removing the character, json_decode works. Anyone know a way to filter out such characters in the json before doing the json_decode()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove control characters with `str_replace` :

```
$specialChars = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 0x20; $i++) {
    $specialChars[] = chr($i);
}
$json = str_replace($specialChars, '?', $json);
```